# InPrivate browsing

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

Is there a way to make IE 8 open in InPrivate browsing mode?

Answer (score 7):

Short answer: Start IE8 with the -private switch.

Long answer: To create an icon on your desktop to directly start Internet Explorer in Private mode, follow these steps:

1. Right click on the desktop, select New -> Shortcut
2. Click Browse and navigate to c:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe, hit OK
3. In the location box (which should now say "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe") add -private to the end of the line.
4. Click Next
5. Type a name like "Internet Explorer Private Mode"
6. Click Finish

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Windows 7, you can click on the arrow on the right hand side of the Internet Explorer link, and select Start InPrivate Browsing.

Not 100% sure if this option is available in Windows Vista.